# "Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running" with a real pfx signed jar

Tags: java, security, applet, jarsigner

I actually jarsign a java applet with this command :

```
jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_real_certificate.pfx my_applet.jar my_alias_certificate -storepass my_password
```

When I launch my applet, I get the following error :

> Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running

When I want to verify the jar, the result appears as following :

> jar verified.
>
> Warning: This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's
>   ExtendedKeyUsage extension doesn't allow code signing. This jar
>   contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated. This jar
>   contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a
>   timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the
>   signer certificate's expiration date (2017-05-22) or after any future
>   revocation date.

For this warning :

> This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's
>   ExtendedKeyUsage extension doesn't allow code signing

I guess my certificate is not proper for jarsigning code. Could you tell me if this kind of warning would get me that kind of error on the client ? Or could I still use this certificate ?

For this warning :

> This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

I don't understand because my certificate was really validated by a CA (Thawte). Should I indicate to Java or into my Windows certificate manager the complete certificate chain (with CA Root and intermediate) ? If so, what happens for the users of this applet ? Should they also do this ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess my certificate is not proper for jarsigning code.

Correct.

> Could you tell me if this kind of warning would get me that kind of error on the client ?

Yes.

> Or could I still use this certificate ?

Not for code signing.  (It could be valid for other purposes though.)

> I don't understand because my certificate was really validated by a CA (Thawte).

That doesn't seem to be the problem.

> Should I indicate to Java or into my Windows certificate manager the complete certificate chain (with CA Root and intermediate) ?

I don't think that would work.  And even if it did ...

> If so, what happens for the users of this applet ?

They will still find that the JAR that won't run >>for them<<.

> Should they also do this ?

Bad idea.  You are effectively telling them to compromise their security to run your software ... because you haven't used a valid JAR signing key.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive answer !

Comment: Really!! @Thordax